# No option to import MAVEN project IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I was trying to import an existing maven project in to IDEA (latest community version) but I do not see `Maven` in the import section of IDE. I'm sure that I have pom.xml in my project. Any Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you on? I get different options when opening files that specify the following:
Eclipse Project or classpath file,
Maven project file,
Gradle build script

I'm on version Ultimate 13.1.6

Comment: I'm on the same version. Moreover, i see the same version on other pc showing maven options. I have set maven home in the env variables as well. Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Have you set the Maven home in IntelliJ's Settings? Press Ctrl+Alt+S and search for `maven home`, see if that has been set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Maven Integration plugin is installed (it usually is by default) you should be able to import a pom.xml file, or more simply, if you are happy with IntelliJ assuming some basic default settings, you can open it directly, as if it were an IntelliJ project, using `File | Open`.  See [Importing Project from Maven Model](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/importing-project-from-maven-model.html)

Assuming that you have maven installed on your system, and you have told IntelliJ where it is (`Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Maven home directory`) it should work for you. Check those settings and try the basic import:

> 1. On the main menu, choose `File | Open`.
> 2. In the dialog box that opens, select the desired `pom.xml` file, and click `OK`.

Comment: I had the same problem of @VishalSharma. The plugin, if already installed, can be enabled by going to settings -> plugin settings -> (tab) Installed.